# Disk Quota with Systemd Nspawn

Tags: systemd

I have a setup where I need to run several apps, each one in a different container. I'm trying to setup a "disk quota" system using systemd-nspawn, to limit the disk space each one would be enabled to use. I'm using BTRFS and I was thinking in a similar way of the CPUQuota option. However, I could not find the right option in systemd-nspawn. I'm new to this container stuff so, one I approach I could think about is starting the container via service file and change its size via "machinectl set-limit" command. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

BTRFS quota is done on top of `subvolumes`.
One possible approach, then is to create subvolumes and set their quotas before binding to the container.

I hope the links below can help you:

1. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/btrfs
2. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/User:I2Oc9/Btrfs_subvolumes

This is not as simple as having `CPUQuota = 10%` on your `.service` file but should work. You can wrap this warm up in a setup script to make it smoother and reduce code duplication.